# Reset a setInterval function with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, timer, refresh

Here my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mid_select').live('click', function(e){ 
        $('#middle').load( $(this).attr('href') + ' #middle');
        var page =  $(this).attr("rel");
        alert(page);
        if (page == 'mywall'){
            var auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
            $('#bottom_middle').load('includes/main_middle_div.php?view=mywall #bottom_middle').fadeIn("slow");}, 5000); 
        } else {
            clearInterval(auto_refresh);     
        }
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }); 
});
```

What I'm trying to do is, if the user clicks on a link with an id of `#mid_select` and a `rel` attribute that equals "mywall", then refresh the `#bottom_middle` div every 5 seconds, but if the user clicks on a link where the `rel` attribute does not equal "mypage" then don't refresh the `#bottom_middle` div every 5 seconds.  Haven't been able to figure out how to get this done, help anyone?

Comment: Post your html on jsfiddle. You don't need this part:

     else {
            clearInterval(auto_refresh);     
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to store a reference to the `setInterval`s timeout **outside** the click handler (using `var`). Also, you have to make sure that a maximum of **one** interval is looping at a time. The adjusted code, as shown below meets these criteria:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var auto_refresh = false;   // Store this variable OUTSIDE the click handler
    $('#mid_select').live('click', function(e){
        var $this = $(this);
        $('#middle').load( $this.attr('href') + ' #middle');
        var page =  $this.attr("rel");
        alert(page);
        if (page == 'mywall'){
            // Check whether an instance is already running...
            if (auto_refresh === false) {
                // NO var, because we use the auto_refresh var in the parent scope
                auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
            $('#bottom_middle').load('includes/main_middle_div.php?view=mywall #bottom_middle').fadeIn("slow");
                }, 5000); 
        } else {
            // Clear interval, and explicitly set it to true
            clearInterval(auto_refresh);
            auto_refresh = false;
        }
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Yeah Rob, thanks, that works perfectly! One little thing, had to add a `}` to end the `if (auto_refresh === false) {` statement. Thanks again.